# Unable to update a package after making python -> python3 symlink

Tags: 16.04, apt, python

I previously had a Anaconda3 installed in my ubuntu, but then I thought I don't need two pythons installed simultaneously. I removed Anaconda, but then my default python version was changed from 3.5 to 2.7 (I'm using ubuntu 16.04) which I don't know why. So I made a symlink `python -> python3`, but that seems to break updates in my ubuntu. This is the error that I get when I try to upgrade `python-crypto_2.6.1-6ubuntu0.16.04.2_amd64.deb` package using `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

```
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'.
```

which is clearly caused by trying to import a `python2` module. I can solve it by changing where `python` symlink points to. But I was looking for a solution that could prevent future problems, and modifications like this.

Comment: @user535733 I've not removed any of my preinstalled python packages that come with Ubuntu, I removed Anaconda which is a stand alone scientific package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu has a version of Python 2 and a version of Python 3 installed by default.

Even if you don't want to do anything with them yourself, you need to respectfully leave them as they are, because many core programs in Ubuntu are written in Python and depend on Python. As many questions here testify

#### If you break Python, Ubuntu will break

So far you have not broken anything critical. You just need to delete the symlink you created, so that programs looking for `python` will not find `python3` instead and fail horribly.

The default symlinks in 16.04 in `/usr/bin` should look like this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Oct 18 12:13 python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Oct 18 12:13 python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     3777000 Sep 17 13:08 python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Oct 18 12:13 python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4739496 Sep 22 13:18 python3.5
```

You don't say where you created your symlink, but you should remove it and make sure you have `/usr/bin/python` pointing to `/usr/bin/python2.7`.

```
cd /usr/bin ; ls -l           # if you have python -> python3 then
sudo rm python
sudo ln -s python2.7 python
```

Comment: Thanks @Zanna, I guess my mistake was I thought python3 should be the defualt python, version in my ubuntu 16.04, as it was the case, before me deleting the Anaconda. I might have had done something before to point `python` to python3 in my Anaconda path or something along this.  Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Farhad I believe Anaconda makes a change to your PATH to make itself the default python in interactive shells